# How to add cookie to any http.get request in typescript and angular2?

Tags: http, angular, cookies, angular2-services

Seems like `http.get` is forbidden since I don't send the cookie value with the request. If I just surf to the link I will get the response, since the browser send the cookie. How I do the same in typescrip code with angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this link:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html

You can specify RequestOptions (such as header values) with your get request.  I presume you could use that to send the cookie in the way you need.  There's not much else for information in your question, so I think that's as close as I can get.

Http spec:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html